# HP Startup:Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, mosquitto, raspberry-pi3

how can resolve this probelm

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/mosquitto.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mosquitto.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.6.20-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Apr 28 2016 00:01:26)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Fix your php so it's pointing at the correct location of that .so, or remove .so from php's external library list.

Comment: how remove from php external lib.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem by write this commands

```
 sudo pecl install Mosquitto-alpha
```

and created mosquitto.ini in

/etc/php5/mods-available/mosquitto.ini

and add this code

```
extension=mosquitto.so
```